# Retrieve all the response in socket at one time

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a client-sever program based on Python socket.
The client sends a command to the server and the server responds.
But now, some client can broadcast a message to other clients, so the client can receive more than one response at the same time.

```
data = s.recv(1024)
```

the line of code above will retrieve only one response from the server.
but if I use a while loop like this

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
```

actually, `data=s.recv(1024)` will block the program when there is no data left.
I don't want to block the program and want to retrieve all the responses available in the connection at one time. Can anyone find a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Unless you're using `UDP` you need 1 socket for each client. `s.recv` will always block you need a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`select` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) to wait until the socket is readable or until a timeout has elapsed; you can then perform other processing.  For example:

```
while True:
    # If data can be received without blocking (timeout=0), read it now
    ready = select.select([s], [], [], 0)
    if s in ready[0]:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        # Process data
    else:
        # No data is available, perform other tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the socket (s) non-blocking. This way, it will retrieve all the received responses and when there is none, it will return back. Of course, with non-blocking, you will have to periodically retry.

You could make the socket (s) non-blocking using the setblocking() method:

```
s.setblocking(0)
```

The other option is to use another thread to handle the receive part. This way, your main thread can continue doing its main task and act upon the message only if it receives one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `socket.setblocking` or `socket.settimeout`:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = 'www.google.com'   
PORT = 80             
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.setblocking(0)

s.sendall('Hello, world')
try:
    data = s.recv(1024)
except:
    print 'Oh noes! %s' % sys.exc_info()[0]
s.close()
```

`socket.recv` takes two parameters, the second is a set of flags. If you're on a Linux system, you can do `man recv` for a list of flags you can supply, and their corresponding errors.

Lastly, in general, you can't really **know** that the other side is done with sending you data (unless you're controlling both sides), even if you're both following a protocol. I believe the right way to go about it is to use timeouts, and quit after sending a reset (how you do this will depend upon what protocol you're using).